# Spring Integration, catching exception on error channel prevents return

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a set of simple REST services which are all configured with an `error-channel` to allow a `service-activator` specified bean to catch exceptions.

When an exception does occur, the method in the bean is called, as expected, and I log the exception. However, the caller (i.e. HTTP client) never gets a response.

What do I need to do to return some sort of error (or indeed anything) back to the client?

I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `service-activator` doesn't return anything, but it isn't good for request-reply case. For the top-level HTTP component it doesn't matter if you catch an Exception within `error-channel` or not, it expects response anyway.

Even if you catch and log that exception in your `service-activator` it has to return something specific to the state of the response, e.g. some String message.

In addition you can populate the `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` message header from there or using `<header-enricher>`.

In this case you just should rely on the `TemporaryReplyChannel` from the request message header, hence don't provide any `output-channel` from the end component in the error-flow. But the valid `return` must be there anyway.

Comment: Thanks Artem - almost there! Simply returning an object is sufficient, I should have guessed! But will you just clarify for me please, where the HTTP Status header goes?

Comment: The `HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport` (the foundation for the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>`) has a code to populate `Status Code` for the response. Hence you just can add some desired `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus` value to the message header with `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` key. Since, it an error for you, your `Status Code` should be one of `4**` family and the browser (or HTTP client) will take care about it properly.

Comment: And? Do you need anything else from me? Or is that an indicator that you can accept my answer? :-)

Comment: I started typing another question but I now have it fully working. Many thanks.